# convert string to date and validate date in Big Query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Hello everyone I am trying to filter a table by date, in order to do that i need to convert a field from a table set as string to date (follow_up_date), currently i have a table like this:

| Follow Up Date | Case ID |
| --- | --- |
| - | 1234 |
| na | 1235 |
| null | 1236 |
| 15/02/2022 | 1237 |
| 24/05/2022 | 1238 |

As you can see, there are fields in the date format but set as string, tried using

```
MAX(PARSE_DATE("%d/%m/%Y", follow_up_date)) AS __ordering__0
```

But is not working, as for the other fields which instead of a date have anyting else like -, na, etc, to set a standar value like "not set"

The query that i need to modify is:

```
WITH
  _0 AS (
    SELECT
      follow_up_date AS __follow_up_date__1, case_id_url AS __case_id_url__1
    FROM x.y.z AS _t
    GROUP BY __follow_up_date__1, __case_id_url__1
    ORDER BY __follow_up_date__1 ASC
    LIMIT 30001
  )
SELECT * FROM _0
```

Any thoughts? I will really appreciate the help.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below example for how to properly convert string to date

```
with data as (
  select '-' follow_up_date, '1234' case_id union all
  select 'na', '1235' union all
  select null, '1236' union all
  select '15/02/2022', '1237' union all
  select '24/05/2022', '1238' 
)
select *, 
  safe.parse_date("%d/%m/%Y", follow_up_date) as fixed_date
from data
```

with output

[image]

Comment: nice, but it didnt seem to work, could you explain a bit the formulation of that? Also, how can this be applied for a large number of dates, it seems that is only applying to the only 2 dates available on the example table

Comment: `with data as (...)` was provided for you just so you can run it for test! have you tried?!  or your real use case - just remove that CTE and use only select statement and replace `data` with your real table reference!